# Get scons to distinguish an empty and a non-existing source while rebuilding

Tags: scons, rebuild

While building my program it is important to distinguish between files that don't exists and files that are empty.
However, it appears that `scons` treats them the same and neglect to rebuild a target when a source file changed from one of these states to the other one.

---

### Step by step example:

**Step 0:**

SConstruct

```py
foo = Command('foo', [], 'echo $TARGET is not created here!')
bar = Command('bar', foo, 'touch $TARGET ; test -f $SOURCE')
Default(bar)
```

Result:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
echo foo is not created here!
foo is not created here!
touch bar ; test -f foo
scons: *** [bar] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

My interpretation:

The command for `foo` fails to create the file but it doesn't raise and error so the command for `bar` is run. It checks if `foo` exists and returns an error. Build fails (everything as expected so far).

**Step 1:**

SConstruct:

```py
foo = Command('foo', [], 'touch $TARGET')
bar = Command('bar', foo, 'touch $TARGET ; test -f $SOURCE')
Default(bar)
```

Result:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
touch foo
touch bar ; test -f foo
scons: done building targets.
```

My interpretation:

`foo` is rebuilt because it has changed. This time it creates an empty file. `bar` is rebuild because it failed before. It succeeds this time. The build is successful (still as expected).

**Step 2:**

SConstruct

```py
foo = Command('foo', [], 'echo $TARGET is not created here!')
bar = Command('bar', foo, 'touch $TARGET ; test -f $SOURCE')
Default(bar)
```

Result:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
echo foo is not created here!
foo is not created here!
scons: `bar' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

My interpretation:

`foo` is rebuilt because it has changed again (was restores to the previous version). The file `foo` doesn't exist any longer because `scons` removes files before building them and the command fails to recreate it. `bar` is not rebuilt because `scons` doesn't seem to detect a change in the source file.
The build is successful while it shouldn't!

---

How can I force `scons` to rebuild `bar` in the last step?

The solution should scale well to "foo" commands that produce many files, list of which is generated programmatically in `SConscript` and cannot be hard-coded.

Comment: *The command for foo fails to create the file but it doesn't raise and error* - why should it fail without raising an error? Isn't that a bug in your command? Curious to what circumstances may force this when building your program.

Comment: @Andreas The command `foo` may or may not create the file and both are correct results, not errors. The command `bar`, however, need the file and should succeed only if it exists. This makes much more sense when you see the full code but it has hundreds of lines.

Comment: I can relate to that scenario. I'm no SCons expert, but maybe a `Scanner` on `bar` can do something useful.

Comment: `Scanner` only finds includes/imports in the file to automatically add them to the list of dependencies. However, this gives me an idea to write a custom `Decider` which should allow me to replace default comparison of files via MD5 signature with my own algorithm. I think, I could the custom decider on the file produced by `foo`.

Comment: @Andreas In the previous message, I forgot the link to documentation of `Decider`: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch06.html

Comment: Opened discussion: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237776/69427947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, scons does now distinguish between emtpy and nonexistent, that's a fairly recent change (commit 3b7f8b4ce0, github.com/SCons/scons/pull/3833).

Comment: What would be the minimum version required?

Comment: That change first appeared in 4.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The default way SCons determines is file has hanged is to compare MD5 signatures of the previous and the current versions of the file.
The signature for a non-existent file is calculated from 0 bytes of data just like for an empty file so SCons doesn't see a difference between them. This is normally OK, especially that not creating the target file isn't an entirely legitimate use of SCons.
However, we can make it work by supplying different function that decides if files are different.

Such function in SCons is called a `Decider`.
There are three of them provided out of the box. The default one uses MD5. The second one uses timestamp. The third one uses MD5 but only if the timestamp is different.

In this case, timestamp could perhaps work because it is 0 for a non-existent file. However, it would generate false-positives when timestamp changes and the contents of the file do not.

Instead, we can supply our own decider which will do exactly what we want it to:

```py
from os import path

env = DefaultEnvironment()
decider_env = env.Clone()

def decide_if_changed(dependency, target, prev_ni, repo_node=None):
    csig = dependency.get_csig() # it has to be called every time or the value won't be in `prev_ni` for the next check
    return not path.isfile(dependency.abspath) or not hasattr(prev_ni, 'csig') or prev_ni.csig != csig
decider_env.Decider(decide_if_changed)

foo = env.Command('foo', [], 'echo $TARGET is not created here!')
bar = decider_env.Command('bar', foo, 'touch $TARGET ; test -f $SOURCE')
Default(bar)
```

This custom decider is similar to the default implementation based on MD5 except it also reports a change if the file doesn't exist.
This should cover the problem described in the question.

The new decider is assigned to a clone of the default environment. This way we have control over which target uses it. In this case only `bar` uses the non-default decider.

Comment: By the way, scons *does* now distinguish between emtpy and nonexistent, that's a fairly recent change (commit 3b7f8b4ce0, https://github.com/SCons/scons/pull/3833).

Comment: @MatsWichmann Linux Mint's official repository has an old version (almost 2 years). I've removed it and installed SCons through pip and it works (facepalm).

Answer (score -1):

If you're saying "how can I force SCons to do xyz?", then you're understanding of SCons is incomplete.

SCons will only build targets which are out of date.

Unless..

You use `AlwaysBuild(target)` see: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#f-AlwaysBuild

It also seems like you never want foo to be removed before it's (re)built?

Then you should use `Precious(target)` see: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#f-Precious

Also.. it's bad form to call a builder with an empty source.

How would SCons ever know if it's out of date?

For your example what causes `foo` to be (re)built?

Comment: `AlwaysBuild` is an option... but a bad one. Too many things would be rebuilt every time. I want SCons to rebuilt targets only if they're out of date but currently it doesn't detect it correctly.

Comment: `Precious` is not an option. This target is supposed to create the file only in certain circumstances. Admittedly, SCons doesn't appear to like it and it will try to rebuilt the target every time when there's no file but it doesn't change much in my case because sources for this target change all the time anyway, in my configuration.

Comment: The empty source is empty only in the example.

Comment: Can you explain "This target is supposed to create the file only in certain circumstances." specifically. Broad generalities aren't going to be sufficient to be able to help you.

Comment: My real code have many hundreds of lines and spans several `SConscript` files. I won't be able explain how it works in a few words. You are trying to find a different solution to my problem or bypass it somehow but I'm already aware of these options. I've chosen this approach because it doesn't require me to rewrite a big hunk of this code. Instead, I'm trying to make it work as is. I'm asked a specific question. If you're able to make these 3 lines work as described, it will solve my problem. If not, I'm already know other ways to do it. It's just much more work.