# Rebuild target if it was externally changed while the source remained the same

Tags: scons, revert, rebuild

I have a Flex source file and the result of converting it to C++ both stored in version control.
(Pretty common practice. This allows compiling the program on machines that don't have Flex installed.)

In some situations, operations on version control may downgrade the target file while the source remains in the latest version. (This is intended.)

In such cases, I would like SCons to just build the target again, so it is up to date.
However, it doesn't detect that the target file is outdated. It seems to only check if the source file has changed.
Can I make SCons also check for changes in the target file while it's deciding if a rebuild is required?

---

You can test that behavior, using this one-line `SConstruct`:

```py
Command('b', 'a', 'cp $SOURCE $TARGET')
```

If you have this `SConstruct` file and you run the following commands:

```sh
echo foo >a
scons -Q b
echo bar >b
scons -Q b
```

you get the this result:

```
+ echo foo >a
+ scons -Q b
cp a b
+ echo bar >b
+ scons -Q b
scons: `b' is up to date.
```

Comment: Is there something odd about how things are generated/built here? The plumbing should "just work", except for machines that don't have flex, in which case the lex tool won't initialize and SCons won't know anything about .ll or .l files.

Comment: @MatsWichmann There is a condition `if WhereIs('flex'): CXXFile(target, source)` so it works correctly without flex (although, you're unable to edit the grammar). This is not a problem specific to flex, though. I've checked it with a one-line SConstruct `Command('b', 'a', 'cp $SOURCE $TARGET')`. It still rebuilds only if the source has changed, ignoring changes in the target.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think "if target out of date with respect to source" is a pretty fundamental concept, if nothing changed in the source, or in the build command ("action") don't think it looks further. We'll see if wiser heads know better....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As demorgan has suggested in their answer, the solution is to write a new [decider](https://scons.org/doc/0.98.2/HTML/scons-user/c779.html), which takes the target into consideration while calculating the result.

However, it is not necessary to write a custom code that stores the previous hash value. We can use the same mechanism that is used to store in the SCons database previous hash values of dependencies.
If we use function `my_file.get_csig()` it will not only return the current hash for this file but also will store it, so it is accessible via `my_file.get_stored_info().csig` the next time.

(Remember to call `get_csig()` each time even if you don't need its value this time, to ensure the stored value is not outdated. Also remember that the object returned by `get_stored_info()` doesn't always have the field `csig`, just like the object `prev_ni`, so you need to check for that field in both cases.)

Here is an example of a custom decider that check hashes of the dependency and the target and cause a rebuild if any of them has changed:

```py
def source_and_target_decider(dependency, target, prev_ni, repo_node=None):
    src_old_csig = prev_ni.csig if hasattr(prev_ni, 'csig') else None
    src_new_csig = dependency.get_csig()
    print(f'"{dependency}": {src_old_csig} -> {src_new_csig}')
    
    tgt_stored_info = target.get_stored_info()
    tgt_old_csig = tgt_stored_info.ninfo.csig if hasattr(tgt_stored_info.ninfo, 'csig') else None
    tgt_new_csig = target.get_csig()
    print(f'"{target}": {tgt_old_csig} -> {tgt_new_csig}')
    
    return src_new_csig != src_old_csig or tgt_new_csig != tgt_old_csig

Decider(source_and_target_decider)
Command('b', 'a', action=Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the documentation (https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp140211724034880), SCons will decide based on the input file. Only deleting the target will trigger a re-build since the target won't exist anymore.

For your case what you need is a Decider and this is documented under:

https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp140211709501040

I wrote a small example with a decider that will always decide that the target has to be rebuild:

```
def my_decider(dependency, target, prev_ni, repo_node=None):
    print("Executing my decider...")
    print("dep: %s " % dependency)
    print("target: %s" % target)
    print("prev_ni: %s" % prev_ni)
    print("repo node: %s" % repo_node)
    return True

Decider(my_decider)
Command('b', 'a', action=[
        Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"),
    ]
)
```

The checksum for the target should be somewhere in the database of SCons and to retrieve it you can check the api:

https://scons.org/doc/latest/PDF/scons-api.pdf

If not get_timestamp() function should return the timestamp of the target. You can save this everytime in another file and then compare it in your decider.

**EDIT**

Below there is a possible implementation solution (yes it is with a file that you can ignore using the versioning system). This will work starting from the third build, since the decider is called twice with different targets....Also the decider for the files is left away intentionally, the code is already in the manual for the dependency part. I don't understand that SCons behavior at this moment and will try to get a solution for that later, since it requires too much time :)

```
import os

already_calculated = False

def get_name(target):
    return "." + str(target)

def store_hash(target):
    with open(get_name(target), "w+") as f:
        f.write(target.get_content_hash())
    f.close()

def get_hash(target):
    if not os.path.exists(get_name(target)):
        return None
    with open(get_name(target), "r") as f:
        return f.readline()

def my_decider(dependency, target, prev_ni, repo_node=None):
    global already_calculated
    if already_calculated:
        return
    already_calculated = True 
    if get_hash(target) == None:
        store_hash(target)
        return True
    old_hash = get_hash(target)
    new_hash = target.get_content_hash()
    if old_hash != new_hash:
        store_hash(target)
        return True
    return False

Decider(my_decider)
Command('b', 'a', action=[
        Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"),
    ]
)
```

Comment: The decider I was writing is as already mentioned an example for the concept and it is definitely not intended to be exactly the code that you have to write. I could of course update my answer with the missing if statement where you have to compare the old target md5 with the new target md5. This is why I provided the link to the api documentation, there you could find all these methods :) As for storage, I never wrote inside the scons dblite since the situation mentioned by you should be avoided using the version control system :) You could also write your own builder.

Comment: Here's an answer that sheds some light on writing deciders based on MD5 sum: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69447566/3052438

Comment: I have added an edit with a possible implementation solution. I am trying to help you, not to get the bounty. I know myself when I was in a legacy environment with a huge scons framework and I had to face strange limitations :) And I like SCons. The solution is dirty because an elegant one requires more time. I can have a look later when I have more time.

Comment: The current solution doesn't rebuild when `a` changes and rebuild twice when `b` changes but I think it results from lack of testing rather than from the chosen approach.
I would try to extract the previous data from SCons database instead of storing it in files (especially that many files). I'm pretty sure this information is/can be stored but there may not be any official method of extracting it. I'll investigate that later.

Comment: I knew it can be done without additional files (see my answer). Programming is all about being stubborn and forcing the computer to do what you intend it to do :-)