# SCons generates an incomplete dependency tree if I use a custom decider

Tags: scons

I'm trying to build a flex-bison parser with SCons, using a custom decider. (You can learn more about the decider in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69621539/3052438), although, the details probably aren't too relevant to the current problem.)

## Files:

My `SConstruct`:

```py
env = DefaultEnvironment()

deciderEnv = env.Clone()
def source_and_target_decider(dependency, target, prev_ni, repo_node=None):
    src_old_csig = prev_ni.csig if hasattr(prev_ni, 'csig') else None
    src_new_csig = dependency.get_csig()
    tgt_stored_info = target.get_stored_info()
    tgt_old_csig = tgt_stored_info.ninfo.csig if hasattr(tgt_stored_info.ninfo, 'csig') else None
    tgt_new_csig = target.get_csig()
    return src_new_csig != src_old_csig or tgt_new_csig != tgt_old_csig
deciderEnv.Decider(source_and_target_decider)

deciderEnv['YACCFLAGS'] = ['-d']
deciderEnv['YACCHXXFILESUFFIX'] = '.hh'
bison_source = deciderEnv.CXXFile('src/test.yy.cc', 'src/test.yy')[0]

deciderEnv['LEXFLAGS'] = [f'--header-file=${{SOURCE}}.hh']
flex_source = deciderEnv.CXXFile('src/test.ll.cc', 'src/test.ll')[0]

Program('test', [bison_source, flex_source])
```

`src/test.yy`:

```cpp
%language "c++"

%code {
    int yylex(int*);
}

%token X

%%

everything: X {}
```

and `src/test.ll`:

```cpp
%{
    #include "./test.yy.hh"
%}

%option c++

%%

. { return yy::parser::token::X; }
```

## Result:

I run a command `scons ./src/test.ll.o`.
The first time you run it, it works correctly.

```
flex --header-file=src/test.ll.hh -t src/test.ll > src/test.ll.cc
bison -d -o src/test.yy.cc src/test.yy
g++ -o src/test.ll.o -c src/test.ll.cc
```

SCons seems to understand that it needs to generate `src/test.yy.hh` using `bison` before it compiles the `src/test.ll.o` because `src/test.ll.cc` `#include`s that header.

However, if I then remove `.sconsign.dblite` (leaving the rest of the files intact), SCons seems to lose that understanding for the duration of the next build.
Running `scons ./src/test.ll.o` yields:

```
flex --header-file=src/test.ll.hh -t src/test.ll > src/test.ll.cc
g++ -o src/test.ll.o -c src/test.ll.cc
```

and only after calling it a second time it decides to build the `src/test.yy.hh`:

```
bison -d -o src/test.yy.cc src/test.yy
g++ -o src/test.ll.o -c src/test.ll.cc
```

## Dependency tree:

Normally the dependency tree (`scons --tree=all src/test.ll.o`) looks like this:

```
+-src/test.ll.o
  +-src/test.ll.cc
  | +-src/test.ll
  | +-/bin/flex
  +-src/test.yy.hh
  | +-src/test.yy
  | +-/bin/bison
  +-/bin/g++
```

However, right after deleting the `.sconsign.dblite` it is incomplete:

```
+-src/test.ll.o
  +-src/test.ll.cc
  | +-src/test.ll
  | +-/bin/flex
  +-/bin/g++
```

## Further observations:

The last line of the custom decider seems to be the culprit.
Specifically, the part `or tgt_new_csig != tgt_old_csig`. If you remove this part, the problem no longer occurs.

However, I have no clue why this particular piece of code breaks the build.

---

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The sconsign is where SCons stores info about previous builds.

If you remove it, then SCons will not have that info and will rebuild everything.

Because in your decider you are setting:

```
tgt_old_csig = tgt_stored_info.ninfo.csig if hasattr(tgt_stored_info.ninfo, 'csig') else None
```

and then comparing None to the current csig, which will not be equal and require a rebuild.

You'd likely need to change as follows to work when you're explicitly removing the source of the tgt_stored_info (the sconsign file).

```
def source_and_target_decider(dependency, target, prev_ni, repo_node=None):
    src_old_csig = prev_ni.csig if hasattr(prev_ni, 'csig') else None
    src_new_csig = dependency.get_csig()
    tgt_stored_info = target.get_stored_info()
    tgt_old_csig = tgt_stored_info.ninfo.csig if hasattr(tgt_stored_info.ninfo, 'csig') else None
    tgt_new_csig = target.get_csig()

    if tgt_old_csig:
        return src_new_csig != src_old_csig or tgt_new_csig != tgt_old_csig
    else:
        return src_new_csig != src_old_csig
```

Why are you removing .sconsign.dblite?

Comment: I know removing `.sconsign.dblite` is supposed to cause SCons to rebuild all the files and I would be very happy if it would do that. Unfortunately it isn't. That's why I'm asking this question. Could you give it one more read, especially the sections `Result` and `Dependency trees`?

Comment: As for why I'm deleting `.sconsign.dblite`. Well, this was the simplest and most clear cut way to reproduce the problem. It happens also in other circumstances. Although, I sometimes do remove the `.sconsign.dblite`, for example while doing `git clean -dfx`.

Comment: Try changing your decider per above? Does that help?

Comment: Hmm.strange. Investigating.

Comment: Your change does fix the problem. I don't understand why, though. I can see it will return `False` when the source file didn't change and we have no information about the target but I was convinced it is fine to return `True` in such cases. Why not?

Comment: I might be wrong about the problem occurring also in other situations. It seems every operation that triggers it ends up deleting `.sconsign.dblite` in one way or another.